# Jquery multiple selectors?

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following HTML markup:

```
<select name="Fault" class="textbox" id="fault">
<option>Single Light Out</option>
<option>Light Dim</option>
<option>Light On In Daytime</option>
<option>Erratic Operating Times</option>
<option>Flashing/Flickering</option>
<option>Causing Tv/Radio Interference</option>
<option>Obscured By Hedge/Tree Branches</option>
<option>Bracket Arm Needs Realigning</option>
<option>Shade/Cover Missing</option>
<option>Column In Poor Condition</option>
<option>Several Lights Out (please state how many)</option>
<option>Column Leaning</option>
<option>Door Missing/Wires Exposed</option>
<option>Column Knocked Down/Traffic Accident</option>
<option>Lantern Or Bracket Broken Off/Hanging On Wires</option>
<option>Shade/Cover Hanging Open</option>
</select>

<span id="faulttext" style="color:Red; display:none">Text in the span</span>


<select name="Fault" class="textbox" id="faultw">
<option>Single Light Out</option>
<option>Light Dim</option>
<option>Light On In Daytime</option>
<option>Erratic Operating Times</option>
<option>Flashing/Flickering</option>
<option>Causing Tv/Radio Interference</option>
<option>Obscured By Hedge/Tree Branches</option>
<option>Bracket Arm Needs Realigning</option>
<option>Shade/Cover Missing</option>
<option>Column In Poor Condition</option>
<option>Several Lights Out (please state how many)</option>
<option>Column Leaning</option>
<option>Door Missing/Wires Exposed</option>
<option>Column Knocked Down/Traffic Accident</option>
<option>Lantern Or Bracket Broken Off/Hanging On Wires</option>
<option>Shade/Cover Hanging Open</option>
</select>

<span id="faulttextw" style="color:Red; display:none">Text in the span</span>
```

and the following jquery script:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#fault option:nth-child(n+12)').wrapAll('<optgroup label="Urgent Faults">');

$('#faultw option:nth-child(n+12)').wrapAll('<optgroup label="Urgent Faults">');

$("#fault").change(function (event) {
    var $selected = $(this).find("option:selected");
    $("#faulttext").fadeToggle(!!$selected.closest("optgroup").length);
});

$("#faultw").change(function (event) {
    var $selected = $(this).find("option:selected");
    $("#faulttextw").fadeToggle(!!$selected.closest("optgroup").length);
});

});
```

Notice that there are two select lists and two spans, the second set is suffixed with a w.

Also notice that the above jquery is duplicated to deal with the suffixed set of elements.

How would i modify/tidy the above jquery to deal with both?

Using `#fault, #faultw option:nth-child(n+12)` as a selector doesn't seem to work.

Also on the second bit of the jquery, if i am to handle the change event using `$("#fault, #faultw").change` then i would need to `fadeToggle` the matching span text.

Or is it best to keep it simple and leave it as it is?

Comment: `$('#fault, #faultw').find('option:nth-child(n+12)');` or
`$('option:nth-child(n+12)','#fault, #faultw');` will produce the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comma acts like an OR, thereby starting an unrelated selector - the `option:nth-child(n+12)` part at the end only applies to the rest of the selector after the comma, not the selector before it as well. You'll need to use: `#fault option:nth-child(n+12), #faultw option:nth-child(n+12)`.

As for the `change` event handler, you could use a HTML5 `data-*` attribute on the `<select>` element to specify the ID of the span to work with.

HTML:

```
<select name="Fault" class="textbox" id="fault" data-spanid="faulttext">
    // options
</select>

<span id="faulttext" style="color:Red; display:none">Text in the span</span>


<select name="Fault" class="textbox" id="faultw" data-spanid="faulttextw">
    // options
</select>

<span id="faulttextw" style="color:Red; display:none">Text in the span</span>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#fault, #faultw").change(function (event) {
    var $selected = $(this).find("option:selected");
    $("#" + $(this).data('spanid')).fadeToggle(!!$selected.closest("optgroup").length);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use selector `#fault option:nth-child(n+12), #faultw option:nth-child(n+12)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#fault option:nth-child(n+12) , #faultw option:nth-child(n+12)').wrapAll('<optgroup label="Urgent Faults">');

$("#fault , #faultw").change(function (event) {
    var $selected = $(this).find("option:selected");
    var id  =   $(this).attr('id');

    $("#"+id).fadeToggle(!!$selected.closest("optgroup").length);
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

The most unobtrusive way, would be to make it depend on the actual position of the select in the DOM. `.nextAll('selector')` looks for that.

```
$("#fault, #faultw").change(function (event) {
    var $selected = $(this).find("option:selected");
    $(this).nextAll('#faulttext,#faulttextw').first().fadeToggle(!!$selected.closest("optgroup").length);
});
```